# Emails not saving to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, email, insert

Hi I am wondering if someone could take a look at my code and see what error there is as I cant see any. what is happening is that it is not saving the emails I am sending it to the mysql, and instead I get a bounced email back.

When I run PHP test to see if it saves to the mysql table, it does not.

I have taken out the connect code as it has my username and password.

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
mysql_connect("123.123.123.2", "abc_ard", "5555") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("55_servermail") or die(mysql_error());

chdir(dirname(__FILE__));
$fd = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
$email = "";
while (!feof($fd)) {
    $email .= fread($fd, 1024);
}
fclose($fd);

if(strlen($email)<1) {
    die(); 
}

// handle email
$lines = explode("\n", $email);

// empty vars
$from = "";
$to="";
$subject = "";
$headers = "";
$message = "";
$splittingheaders = true;

for ($i=0; $i < count($lines); $i++) {
    if ($splittingheaders) {
        // this is a header
        $headers .= $lines[$i]."\n";
        // look out for special headers
        if (preg_match("/^Subject: (.*)/", $lines[$i], $matches)) {
            $subject = $matches[1];
        }
        if (preg_match("/^From: (.*)/", $lines[$i], $matches)) {
            $from = $matches[1];
        }
        if (preg_match("/^To: (.*)/", $lines[$i], $matches)) {
            $to = $matches[1];
        }
    } else {
        // not a header, but message
        $message .= $lines[$i]."\n";
    }
    if (trim($lines[$i])=="") {
        // empty line, header section has ended
        $splittingheaders = false;
    }
}


mysql_query("INSERT INTO mail
(`to`,`from`,`header`,`subject`,`msg`,`original`)
VALUES
('{$to}','{$from}', '{$headers}','{$subject}','{$message}','{$email}')") or die(mysql_error());;


?>
```

Comment: Can you print out the query text and feed it directly into mysql database? And your words are very unclear.

Comment: can you post the sample values that you'll be putting on the fields for the email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When adding information to mysql you have to account for characters used by mysql and PHP and address them as they can cause code to fail, and even allow people to insertand/or execute code on your site. The simplest method I have used is to have PHP "escape" the characters to allow them to insert into mysql properly as follows:

```
$email = "This isn't my first time 'round here";
```

This should insert fine as is, but let's presume that your SQL is like this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table (timestamp,email) VALUES (time(),'$email')";
```

the single quotes in the MySQL query will be jacked up by the single quotes in your data. In order to avoid this set your email variable to be escaped:

```
$email = "This isn't my first time 'round here"; 
$email = mysql_escape_string($email);
```

The caviat to using this is that now your database has extra escape characters (typically a backslash "/") in your data, so when you want to use these from the database you will have to remove them and PHP has a handy function just for this:

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='the id you want'"; 
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $email = stripslashes($data['email']);
    }

    echo "This is your email text from the database: <br>\n".$email."<br>\n";
```

Hope that helps to clarify one possible solution (if that is indeed why the email is not inserting into the database as expected).

Answer (score 0):

the only error that I could possibly see in this current code is the possibility of entering characters like apostrophe(') please verify that if you want it to be included on the message body or other fields make sure to use the backslash() e.g (\') so that mysql will analyze it as a charater and not a closing apostrophe, but do have a security measure on doing that to avoid sql injection. :)